# Get details of XDocument with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XDocument

```
<results>
<team id="1" name="Manchester United">
    <player name="Ryan Giggs" position="midfielder" />
    <player name="Wayne Rooney" position="striker" />
    <player name="Rio Ferdinand" position="defender" />
</team>
<team id="2" name="Liverpool">
    <player name="Steven Gerrard" position="midfielder" />
    <player name="Luis Suarez" position="striker" />
    <player name="John Terry" position="defender" />
</team>
<team id="1" name="Manchester City">
    <player name="Kolo Toure" position="midfielder" />
    <player name="Samuel Eto" position="striker" />
    <player name="Vincent Company" position="defender" />
</team>
</results>
```

and I wish to get all the data as follows

```
IEnumerable<Teams> (TeamID and TeamName)
IEnumerable<PLayers> (TeamID, PlayerName, Position)
```

At the moment I have the following

```
XElement results = doc.Root.Element("results");
var teams =
    (from p in results.Descendants("team")
     select new
     {
         Id = utils.GetDecimal(p.Element("id").Value),
         TeamName = p.Element("name")
     }).ToList();
```

However this is throwing an error.

Then my idea is to do the same for each team and get the team's players.

What do I have wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `id` is not an element, it is an Attribute
2. You shouldn't use `Value` property, it throws exception if the element wasn't found, instead use  explicit cast.
3. Also create a class for your teams and players instead of creating anonymous types.

   ```
   var teams = (from p in results.Descendants("team")
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = utils.GetDecimal((string)p.Attribute("id")),
                        TeamName = (string)p.Element("name"),
                        Players = p.Elements("player")
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                            Position = (string)x.Attribute("position")
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    }).ToList();
   ```

Comment: About "Do not use Value property" : what if he expects null/empty values?

Comment: You're generally right but you are making assumptions. Like with the 'don't use anonymous' advice.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes you are right, I made that mistake of calling it an Element instead of Attribut!  This worked thanks!

Comment: Hi I just tried this again but its not working, getting "Object not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: The problem is this :-              XElement results = doc.Root.Element("results");